# Replacement of <xsl:eval> and <xsl:script> in XSL

Tags: xslt

I am trying to modify an xsl which is of the older version. I come across the following:

```
<xsl:eval>FormatAccount(this)</xsl:eval>

<xsl:script>
    function FormatAccount(e) {
       // function details
    }
</xsl:script>
```

I am trying to call the `FormatAccount()` javascript function using `<xsl:eval>` and the function is written in `<xsl:script>`.

How to do this as per the latest standards?

Comment: With input sample and desired output this could be done with XSLT only.

Comment: The language you describe is not XSLT at all. There is  no W3C spec of any version that specifies an `<xsl:script>` instruction.

Comment: The above comment is not true. There is a working draft that includes the same http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#stylesheet-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest standard is XSLT 2.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/, it does not have any facility to define functions in Javascript, it however allows you to define functions with XSLT itself: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-functions.
XSLT 2.0 is supported by XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9 http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, AltovaXML Tools http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html or XQSharp http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/beta.htm.

If you want to use Javascript to define extension functions we need to know which XSLT processor you use, of those three XSLT 2.0 processors I mentioned I think only AltovaXML Tools allows that (http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?xextmsxsl.htm), and only, I think, to allow easier migration of XSLT 1.0 stylesheets written for Microsoft MSXML.

If you want to use an XSLT 1.0 processor then there too defining extension functions in a particular programming language like Javascript depends on the processor you use, for MSXML there is an `msxsl:script` element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

**Embedded extension functions in other language is not the content model of XSLT.**

Extension elements and extension functions are part of the content model as described in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#extension : it's implementation dependant how exactly an XSLT processor register those extensions.

As pointed by @Martin Honnen's answer, in XSLT 2.0 you can declare "stylesheet functions" with XSLT itself.

Comment: @Alejandro: any `<xsl:function>` is *not* an extension function. It is a native, xslt function.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right, the proper name from specs is "stylesheet functions".