# why javascript function not call in xslt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I try to call javascript function xslt ? why it is not called?

http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLX

I tried like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:jscript="http://www.url.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl jscript">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
          <xsl:variable name="sVar" select="'ss'"/>

<xsl:value-of select="jscript:getRegion(string($sVar))"/>
        <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="jscript">
function getRegion(sVar){
alert(sVar)
}
</msxsl:script>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

I take reference from here 
[Calling a user defined function written in javascript using xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043681/calling-a-user-defined-function-written-in-javascript-using-xsl)
why alert is not showing

Comment: Why would a stylesheet alert anything? Are you opening this in a browser?

Comment: Not sure about `jscript`, though you can call `javascript` function within `xhtml` `document`.

Comment: sorry for late reply ..yes I need to open in browser

Comment: @guest271314 how we can call

Comment: Have not tried `XSL Transform`, You can use `<script>` element within `xhtml` document.

Comment: So which XSLT processor do you use where you expect `msxsl:script` to be supported? And even when supported, why do you expect the `alert` function, which is not a function implemented by an Javascript engine, but rather by browsers, to work? If you have an XSLT processor like MSXML 3 or 6 supporting `msxsl:script` then you only have support for core objects/functions/data types implemented by the JScript engine https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Calling mechanisms from XSLT to external languages such as Java or Javascript depend entirely on which XSLT processor you are using. You haven't said which XSLT processor you are using, but it is presumably one that either (a) does not support calling to Javascript, or (b) doesn't support calling to Javascript using this particular Microsoft-defined syntax.